# attach multiple as well as single file on button click in android

Tags: android, attachment

It might be a very simple question for some of you. I have a button, on click of which I can attach single or multiple file and I am accessing the file paths in OnActivityResult().  Using (Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true) has let me attach multiple files now. The issue is now I can't select a single file if I want to and have to always select multiple files for the opperation. I am not doing it for sending a mail. Its a simple process of selecting some files and based on the selection, get the  corresponding data from the SD card and upload.

Below I am posting my code for opening the browser and attach files :

```
 txtv_attach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
            Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            chooseFile.setType("*/*");
            chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
            startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

        }
    });
```

Is there any way I can attach both single as well as multiple files? need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Using (Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true) has let me attach multiple files now`. No. The user can select multiple files or one. Thats up to the user. You can let away the extra stream as it does nothing. What should it do you think?

Comment: `I am posting my code for opening the browser and attach files :`??? That is code to let the user select files. There is nothing that attaches. What do you mean by browser?

Comment: Yes..I mean the whole process looks like attachment..you select some items and based on your selection, you will get the path to the selected items. Browser means the file explorer. You can say Google drive

Comment: You have not reacted on my first comment. What you suggest is not true.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. The uri holds the path to the folder which will be opened on button click. In this case, it's the download folder. Is there any other way I can pass the uri without mentioning extrastream? If you know, please do suggest. Once the file explorer opens and items are selected, inside onActiveResult () , I am accessing the path to the selected files.The requirement is to open the file explorer, select files and once files selected and explorer closed, access the selected file paths. That's pretty much covers the whole requirement